# Azure Resource Manager Template: Is there a way to get all resourceId/resourceName of a resource type under a Resource Group?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I wonder if there is a way to get all resources of a particular type under a resource group?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the easiest way to do it is using [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-2.7.0) , try the command below :

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <resource group name>| where {$_.ResourceType -eq <resource type>}  |select Name , ResourceId
```

Result for demo :
[image]

Hope it helps .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry I did not make it clear I want to do it through Azure arm template. I tagged the question as a arm-template question, but forgot to make it more clear in the description. Edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `resourceId()` function for that for a single resource:

```
"[resourceId('otherResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'examplestorage')]"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid

this is not possible for ALL the resources in the resource group unless you know their names beforehand and use resourceId function for each one individually

or you could use external scripts, like the other answer suggests